# Why do my in-kernel dynamic memory allocations fail for larger grid sizes?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpgpu

I need to dynamically allocate some arrays inside the kernel function. Here is the code:

```
__global__
void kernel3(int N)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < N)
    {
        float * cost = new float[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            cost[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

and

```
int main()
{
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    size_t mem_tot_01 = 0;
    size_t mem_free_01 = 0;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&mem_free_01, &mem_tot_01);
    cout << "Free memory " << mem_free_01 << endl;
    cout << "Total memory " << mem_tot_01 << endl;
    system("pause");
    int blocksize = 256;
    int aaa = 16000;
    int numBlocks = (aaa + blocksize - 1) / blocksize;
    kernel3 << <numBlocks, blocksize >> >(aaa);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t err1 = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err1 != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err1));
        system("pause");

    }


    cudaMemGetInfo(&mem_free_01, &mem_tot_01);
    cout << "Free memory " << mem_free_01 << endl;
    cout << "Total memory " << mem_tot_01 << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

In the first round of cudaMemGetInfo:
Free memory:3600826368
Total memory:4294967297

and i got an error:
Error:unspecified launch failure

and i tried to change the "int aaa" to some smaller value, it won't get error but the memory info is not equal to what i assigned. 
What's wrong with it? The memory should be enough, 16000x100x32=512x10e5<3600826368

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device memory allocated by the `new` operator comes from a runtime heap of fixed size.

If your code requires a large amount of runtime heap memory, you will probably need to increase the size of the heap before running any kernels. NVIDIA provide the [cudaDeviceSetLimit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g05956f16eaa47ef3a4efee84563ccb7d)  API for this purpose, which is used with the `cudaLimitMallocHeapSize` flag to set the size of the heap.

Comment: A fine answer generally, but I believe you're just helping OP fix the gun they're using to shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: @einpoklum: Stack Overflow exists to answer questions, not editorialize. The question is why there is memory exhaustion when using in-kernel memory allocation. And that is what I have answered.

Comment: And that's why I had upvoted you (before you wrote your comment). Still, OP did not ask merely the general question appearing in the title - s/he asked about a specific program of his with which s/he is having a problem. So it's at least partially an XY question. Plus, s/he would not come up against the heap size limit if it weren't for the incorrect approach.